# Access 2013 odbc link table Update Query issues

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I have a very large ODBC linked table that I have to use Access 2013 to read. I have editing permissions for the table.

I need to update information in 2 columns for the top 300 entries sorted on one of the columns I am updating. I took 400 entries out of the ODBCtable and put them in a standard access table to develop the correct code to make this happen. I was able to get the correct code and make it work in a standard access table. It was as follows:

```
UPDATE (SELECT TOP 300 [testers 400].AgrCode, [testers 400].RangeCode, [testers 400].UnitNumber, [testers 400].DNSName
FROM [testers 400]
WHERE ((([testers 400].AgrCode) Like "*fran*") AND (([testers 400].RangeCode) Like "*phi*") AND (([testers 400].UnitNumber) Like "F??????"))
ORDER BY [testers 400].UnitNumber)
SET [testers 400].UnitNumber = Right([UnitNumber],6), [testers 400].DNSName = Replace([DNSName],".f",".")
WHERE ((([testers 400].AgrCode) Like "*fran*") AND (([testers 400].RangeCode) Like "*phi*") AND (([testers 400].UnitNumber) Like "F??????"));
```

this returned the Top 300 units and updated only those 300 units out of the 400.

I then went to my ODBC table and ran the same code with the new descriptors:

```
UPDATE (SELECT TOP 300 dbo_TTMSProdActiveIPDNS.AgrCode, dbo_TTMSProdActiveIPDNS.RangeCode, dbo_TTMSProdActiveIPDNS.UnitNumber, dbo_TTMSProdActiveIPDNS.DNSName
FROM dbo_TTMSProdActiveIPDNS
WHERE (((dbo_TTMSProdActiveIPDNS.AgrCode) Like "*fran*") AND ((dbo_TTMSProdActiveIPDNS.RangeCode) Like "*phi*") AND ((dbo_TTMSProdActiveIPDNS.UnitNumber) Like "F??????"))
ORDER BY dbo_TTMSProdActiveIPDNS.UnitNumber)
SET dbo_TTMSProdActiveIPDNS.UnitNumber = Right([UnitNumber],6), dbo_TTMSProdActiveIPDNS.DNSName = Replace([DNSName],".f",".")
WHERE (((dbo_TTMSProdActiveIPDNS.AgrCode) Like "*Fran*") AND ((dbo_TTMSProdActiveIPDNS.RangeCode) Like "*phi*") AND ((dbo_TTMSProdActiveIPDNS.UnitNumber) Like "F??????"));
```

Unfortunately it did not work completely. It found the 300 sites, but it did not run the SET/WHERE section of the command. So none of the 300 sites were updated.

I cannot figure out why it ran the select command, but not the actual update command. i think it has something to do with the fact it is an odbc linked table, but I don't know how to adjust my code to make it work. Please help. I would be interested in using a Pass-through function, but I don't know how to change the above code language to make it work in pass-through. Any ideas would be awesome please.

Comment: You're using both SQL Server and MySQL?

Comment: I am using Access 2013 to link to a SQL Server (odbc table).